# Using Persits Jpeg, is there a way to determine what size to set the font based on the text and image size

Tags: jpeg

I am using the Persits.Jpeg image manipulation tool.

I want to add text to it - the text may be any length.

I want the text to fill the width of the image - I can get the image width.

I can set a font size, place the text on the image and then get the width of the text, but then I have the wrong sized text on the image.

Is there a way of working out how wide the text will be without putting it on the image or maybe a way to remove the just added text.  Yes I know I can reload the image, but I'm trying to avoid that as it is process intensive and I would have to keep saving it after each piece of text is successfully sized.